# Angular HTML element: observe element property within itself

Tags: html, angular, image, typescript, loading

I am trying to attach a directive toggler to an `HTML Element`'s value

the element is an `img`:

`<img src="..." alt="..." [nbSpinner]="boolean">`

I know angular serves an output of `(load)` which fires when the image was fully loaded.

`<img src="..." alt="..." (load)="firedWhenLoaded($event)"`

And I could bind the `[nbSpinner]` Directive to a component boolean such as `loaded` and once the image is fully loaded, convert it to `true`.

But in a case I have an array of images, I am looking to explore an option of doing something like this:

`<img src="..." alt="..." [nbSpinner]="this.loaded">`

Is there any support for this kind of approach?

Comment: what difference does it make for array of images?

Comment: I assume a single component `loaded` field will result in presenting a single loaded image while the rest are still possibly loading. I wish to experiment with a behavior of having a `spinner` for every image in the array which has not yet loaded